# Detect android another application launch event

Tags: android

I am working on an application and I need to be able to have a service that can detect when applications are opened, and take action based on that.

I have looked everywhere, and have not found a way to do so. I have read documentation on broadcast receivers, intent handlers, and I found nothing.

I did however, find an app that can do so - App Protector. It allows password protecting certain applications.

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

I found Detect application launch but its working below api 12. Thanks!

Comment: I guess it is the same as a dinner event.

Comment: What about Second Breakfast events?!

Answer (score 0):

Can this "Detect Application launch" API work if you add/include [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) in your build?

**EDIT:**

I found this thing:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
    if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.browser")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Browser is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

But you must know the package name of the application. To get this, take a look [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon).

This method after APILEVEL 12 is not working.
Cheers.

Comment: Ok, either way, the Support Library could be the key, try including it and see the result.

Comment: Can you please point me where this Detect Application is (sources preferably), so to see how to overcome this. In the meantime I have an idea of this, but let me write it to code.